# React Native Maps Error compile debugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, android-emulator

I'm new to React-native.I try to add google map on my App using `npm i react-native-maps --save`

I refer this https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md and follow the all step. I get the Google API and put it to the **AndroidManifest**. My **Google Play Services version** is **14.5.74**. I also add it `android/app/build.gradle`. Here it is

> ext {
>           buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3" 
>            minSdkVersion = 16 
>           compileSdkVersion = 27
>           targetSdkVersion = 26
>           supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
>             googlePlayServicesVersion = "14.5.74"
>           androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
>       }

and I used to

> "dependencies": {
>       "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
>       "react": "16.5.0",
>       "react-native": "0.57.0",
>       "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1"   },

But I get a error

> ask :**react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED**
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolyline.java:8:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>  import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Cap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class Cap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolyline.java:12:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.RoundCap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class RoundCap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolyline.java:27:
>   error: cannot find symbol   private Cap lineCap = new RoundCap();
>             ^   symbol:   class Cap   location: class AirMapPolyline D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolyline.java:73:
>   error: cannot find symbol   public void setLineCap(Cap cap) {
>                            ^   symbol:   class Cap   location: class AirMapPolyline
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.ButtCap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class ButtCap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:16:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Cap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class Cap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:17:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.RoundCap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class RoundCap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:18:
>   error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.SquareCap;
>                                           ^   symbol:   class SquareCap   location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolyline.java:27:
>   error: cannot find symbol   private Cap lineCap = new RoundCap();
>                               ^   symbol:   class RoundCap   location: class AirMapPolyline
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:77:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       Cap cap = null;
>       ^   symbol:   class Cap   location: class AirMapPolylineManager D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:80:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           cap = new ButtCap();
>                     ^   symbol:   class ButtCap   location: class AirMapPolylineManager
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:83:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           cap = new RoundCap();
>                     ^   symbol:   class RoundCap   location: class AirMapPolylineManager
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:86:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           cap = new SquareCap();
>                     ^   symbol:   class SquareCap   location: class AirMapPolylineManager
>   D:_reactNative\MSB\LocationMap\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapPolylineManager.java:89:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           cap = new RoundCap();
>                     ^   symbol:   class RoundCap   location: class AirMapPolylineManager Note: Some input files use or override a
>   deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 14 errors
>
> - **What went wrong**: Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Please tell how can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native-maps` dependency is not working with `react-native version 0.57.0`. Please update it to 0.57.4 or latest version.